# Blackberry Tablet OS: Development Resources, Guides, Tutorials

Tags: blackberry, sdk, blackberry-playbook, qnx-neutrino

Following the recent announcement of the new Blackberry Tablet OS, it's SDK and Simulator, any ideas where one could find resources and tutorials on how to develop for their new tablet OS? It will be nice for once to catch the wave on time.

Comment: Word, on catching the wave. But really, I'd be happy getting a free PlayBook out of this.. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be useful to learn more about the different components used in Blackberry Tablet OS, like:

- QNX Neutrino, the kernel
- Adobe AIR
- OpenGL ES

You can also look at this:

http://blog.swfjunkie.com/2010/10/getting-started-blackberry-playbook-development-setup/

Comment: I could also add SQLite and Webkit, which are both embedded in AIR. But I don't know how you can use them outside from AIR, as this OS can also be programmed in C and probably Java, for example...

Answer (score 7):

Here http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/

Answer (score 4):

SDK and simulator [installation guide](http://na.isobar.com/2010/beginning-blackberry-tablet-programming/)

Away3D beginners [tutorial](http://na.isobar.com/2010/blackberry-tablet-away3d-animation-programming/)

Adobe AIR / ActionScript tutorials; [1](http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/03/06/25-excellent-and-useful-adobe-air-tutorials-resources.html), [2](http://www.smashingapps.com/2009/03/06/25-excellent-and-useful-adobe-air-tutorials-resources.html), [3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/as3.html), [4](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/), [5](http://active.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/actionscript/)

Flex [tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/flex/)

---

For those of you with windows x64 OS, the mods to be able to install the SDK and Simulator below;

http://blog.swfjunkie.com/2010/10/getting-started-blackberry-playbook-development-setup/

Answer (score 3):

I know an answer has been accepted already, but I figured there will be a lot of readers coming to this post, so let's keep it coming

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21866/BlackBerry_Tablet_OS_SDK_for_Adobe_AIR-Getting_Started_Guide--1348721-1021122745-001-1.0_Beta-US.pdf

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/blackberry_tablet_os_sdk.html

also when you are building for mobile devices(including tablets) keep in mind that it's not all just about compiling in air. There are a lot of things you can do to optimize AIR. Would be nice to know which of these features are supported by Tablet OS, aand hard to test until you get a playbook.Anyhow check this out too: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/fpmobile.html

Mike Chambers did a couple talks on optimization, so do check this out too if you're planning on making games. http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2010/07/14/source-code-for-pewpew-released/

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/

there is a Documentation for Developers tab at left. And you can find Tablet OS Development at there. Hope that will help you.